# Why are protons/neutrons spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ when they are made up of three valence quarks (also spin-$\frac{1}{2}$)?

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks

If we take the composite angular momentum of the three valence quarks, we should have a proton/neutron spin angular momentum of,
$$S=\{ \frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2} \}$$
using the general rule for adding angular momentum in quantum mechanics. Evidently, we only ever observe a proton spin of $\frac{1}{2}$. So my question is, why do we not observe a spin of $\frac{3}{2}$?

Comment: Are you asking why the spin 1/2 state, *p*, is lighter than the spin 3/2 one, $\Delta^+$, made up of the very same valence quarks?

Comment: I suppose that is what my question reduces to after realising that these are made of the same valence quarks @CosmasZachos

Comment: It's a subtle question answered in quark model reviews: the energetics "favor" the spin 1/2 state making it lighter, so the heavier states rearrange to that one, in time...

Comment: @CosmasZachos makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> So my question is, why do we not observe a spin of $\frac{3}{2}$?

Actually we did observe such particles.
But we don't call them proton and neutron,
because they behave differently in some other ways.
See at [Table of Baryons](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/baryon.html).

- The $\Delta^+$ particle.
  It has quark composition $uud$ (i.e. same as the proton)
  and spin $\frac{3}{2}$ (unlike the proton).
- The $\Delta^0$ particle.
  It has quark composition $udd$ (i.e. same as the neutron)
  and spin $\frac{3}{2}$ (unlike the neutron).

The $\Delta$ particles are instable (with very short lifetime)
and have masses around $30$% larger than proton/neutron.
(See [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/465448/why-is-the-proton-uud-lighter-than-the-%CE%940-uud-baryon) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/645541/mass-of-baryons-and-their-spin-state-is-there-any-connection) question about why the mass is larger.)

Comment: Interesting, why would the $\Delta^{+}$ and  $\Delta^{0}$ be more massive? Is it due to the magnetic interactions between the quark spins? I assume that we observe more protons and neutrons because they decay to the lowest mass state.

Answer (score 7):

We don't observe spin 3/2 protons because the proton is, by definition, the spin 1/2 ground state of $uud$. Both $\Delta$ baryons and $N^*$ baryons have/can have higher spins.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks